# laravel unique validation on multiple column while update record

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have to update record ignoring the current record i-e I have implement uniqueness on two column company_id and user_id while insert record the code working perfectly but when I update its not I stuck how can I implement
Here is the code

```
        Validator::extend('ValidateUser', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters) use ($company_id, $user_id) {
        $msgs = CustomReports::where('parent_company', $company_id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->get()->count();
        if ($msgs > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    Validator::replacer('ValidateUser', function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
        return "Custom report is already assign to this user against parent company";
    });

    $this->validate($request,[
        'parent_company_id' => 'required',
        'user' => 'required|ValidateUser',
        'reporting_company_id' => 'required',
        'bifurcation' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use the [existing unique rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique) ? That does support ignoring rows by default

Answer (score 0):

One way of resolve this problem it's use different validation for create and update user